# Here how to get those 102,88 value? similar to 9,43?

Tags: math, encryption, cryptography, curve, elliptic-curve

Public: y^2 = x^3 + 11x + 19 (mod 167) and the point (2,7).  ---------(I)

Alice and Bob each must randomly select their own secret multipliers. Suppose Alice selects A = 15 and Bob selects B = 22. Then Alice computes

**A(2,7) = 15(2,7) = (102,88)**,

where all arithmetic is done on the curve in equation (i). Alice sends her  computed result to Bob. Bob computes

**B(2,7) = 22(2,7) = (9,43)**,

which he sends to Alice. Now Alice multiplies the value she received from  Bob by her secret multiplier A, that is,
A(9,43) = 15(9,43) = (131,140).

Similarly, Bob computes
B(102,88) = 22(102,88) = (131,140)

***Here how to get A for (102,88) and B for (9,43)??***

Comment: Are you asking mathematically or programmatically? Mathematically it is scalar multiplication requires ECC addition and doubling rules, and the double-and-add algorithm. Programatically easiest is SageMath.

Comment: [Scalar multuplication](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68595/18298)

Comment: i want to know just mathematically. how do get those values? Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, then you are in the wrong SE, Here [the formulas](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66296/18298)

Comment: okay thanks. but can you just show me how to get this line?
A(2,7) = 15(2,7) = (102,88),

Comment: Nope. Once or Twice doubling and adding formulas can be done by hand, the rest is error-prone and time-consuming. Use Sagemath.